# How to pass the new incoming Data to another Class after Polling

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, object, methods

This class does Polling and checks for new incoming messages.Now how can i achieve both Polling and check for new data at the same time? At last all the data had to be fed back to the Polling

```
public void run() {
int seqId = 0;
    while(true) {
        List<KamMessage> list = null;
        try {
            list = fullPoll(seqId);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            seqId = list.get(0).getSequence();
            incomingMessages.addAll(list);
            System.out.println("waiting 3 seconds");
            System.out.println("new incoming message");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("new incoming message");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
public List<KamMessage> fullPoll(int lastSeq) throws Exception {
Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION =  804 and SEQ >" +
lastSeq + "order by SEQ DESC");      
    List<KamMessage> pojoCol = new ArrayList<KamMessage>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        KamMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);
        pojoCol.add(filedClass);
    }
    for (KamMessage pojoClass : pojoCol) {
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getSequence());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getTableName());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getAction());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo1());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo2());
        System.out.println(" " + pojoClass.getEntryTime());
    }           
    return pojoCol;
}
```

My task is to Poll the table from the database and also check for new incoming message.After polling first I get the new incoming data, Now my problem is

1.How to pass this new data into another class, to process the message.

2.And how to fed it back to database and call for polling again.

3.How to achieve this in Parallel

Comment: How about accept some answers?

Comment: @Roman C, I already did polling got new incoming data from the console but how get this and pass to another , so that it process the new msg and feed it back to the database